# Visual Studio Web Installer

Tags: visual-studio

I've noticed the visual studio web installer, by default only allows you to setup a virtual directory for an existing website.

Is it possible to get the installer to give you a choice to either create a website or install to an existing website?

If not perhaps I am using the wrong installer product, or do I need to create a custom installer?

I would like to use a free solution. What do you guys recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't

you will mess up with the existing web site, imagine that that website is a pre compiled site (you can't change nothing in this case)

The correct question will be:

> [Is there any way to create a patch for an ASP.Net web application installer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162366)

<strike>You need to create a New **Web Setup project** :)</strike>

Comment: Well to be more accuruate a web setup project, which I have done, but once compiled, and during the install process, it only allows you to install the website to a virtual directory.

Comment: I thought you meant other thing :) then I read 3 more times and figure it out :D

Comment: So this built in visual studio web installer, is only good for installing to virtual directory? And not to its own web site?

Comment: for that you should use a Repository, a Web Setup is a fixed thing, just like an Windows Application, you can UPDATE a Wwindows Application by removing the old version and add the new version. Here at my company I'm responsible of ASP.NET projects and in our clients we do the same. Uninstall the Web Site first (saving the web.config and other xml configuration file first) and then install the new version.